# Crashlytics/Fabric - Will my app crash after deleting Account / project?

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm planning on deleting my crashlytics account.

But before I do that, how do I know the previously released versions of my ios app which talks to crashlytics will continue to work (aside from the crash reporting)?

It shouldn't crash because the account was deleted right? I'm trying to find any documentations that will tell me it won't crash, but I'm not seeing any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Great questions, we recently shipped a docs that will help you to understand what will happen "After March 31, 2020". Her is the [link](https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/fabric-shutdown.html) to the docs. If you still have questions, please reach out us AT 'support@fabric.io'